# Angular2 - Do something when innerHTML changed

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component and its `inner html` is dynamically changing. I do some operation on the child DOM elements of this component, so I have to repeat the operations each time the `inner html` of this component is changed.

For example in the component:

```
myElements = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
// do something with that DOM elements
```

And in the view:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myItems">
    <div class="myClass">...</div>
</div>
```

I have to call

```
myElements = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
```

Each time myItems is updated and new DOM elements loaded.

Can I bind the `innerHTML` to `ngOnChange()` or is there other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try ngDoCheck:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html

You would manually check the old value and the new value of the innerHtml, then execute your custom code.

Potential example:

```
public ngDoCheck(){
    if(this.oldInnerHtml != this.newInnerHtml){
        //take custom action
    }
}
```